# bash 'pattern substitution' fails only in some conditions

Tags: bash, quoting, string

Why does/would the following `printf` statement behave differently based upon ...? (GNU bash, version 4.4.18(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu))

```
printf "%s : %s : %s\n" $TERM  ${TERM//[^[:alnum:]]/_} ${TERM//[^[:alnum:]]/?}
```

When in an unprivileged user terminal session in `tmux`, the output is:

```
screen-256color : screen_256color : screen?256color
```

However, when in a `root` terminal, for the same `tmux` session the output is:

```
xterm-256color : xterm_256color :
```

Outside of `tmux`, the output is the same failure for all users:

```
xterm-256color : xterm_256color :
```

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

I just tried the same command line, but replacing the question mark with an asterisk, and the same failures and successes occur. Could it be an issue related somehow to globbing? The field is supposed to be treated as a string value, not a glob. Then I tried escaping the character and get the following results, for the six cases of asterisk plain, with one backslash, and with two backslashes, for `xterm-256color` and `screen-256-color` cases mentioned above:

```
printf "%s : %s : %s\n" $TERM  ${TERM//[^[:alnum:]]/_} ${TERM//[^[:alnum:]]/*}

screen-256color : screen_256color : screen*256color
xterm-256color : xterm_256color :

printf "%s : %s : %s\n" $TERM  ${TERM//[^[:alnum:]]/_} ${TERM//[^[:alnum:]]/\*}

screen-256color : screen_256color : screen*256color
xterm-256color : xterm_256color :

printf "%s : %s : %s\n" $TERM  ${TERM//[^[:alnum:]]/_} ${TERM//[^[:alnum:]]/\\*}

screen-256color : screen_256color : screen\*256color
xterm-256color : xterm_256color : xterm\*256color
```

Comment: It looks like you're using `screen` for one but not the other. Are you?

Comment: @roaima : No,although both examples were from a single `tmux` session (kind of like `screen`) on the same host. I just tried the example outside of `tmux` and it fails even for a regular account (with TERM=xterm-256color), so I need to update the question. Not sure exactly how to re-frame it yet ...

Comment: What is root's login shell? Is it bash?

Comment: @glennjackman: yes, it is bash, same version. The version of `tmux` is debian package version 2.63

Comment: You and root have different shell options. See below.

Comment: @glennjackman : not relevant, because when running the example as the same unprivileged user, but outside of `tmux`, the same error occurs. It's beginning to correlate to the value of TERM being either `screen-256color` or `xterm-256color` or whether it happens in or out of `tmux`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can reproduce:

```
$ printf "%s : %s : %s\n" $TERM  ${TERM//[^[:alnum:]]/_} ${TERM//[^[:alnum:]]/?}
xterm-256color : xterm_256color :
```

That's because no files match the **pattern** `xterm?256color`

Solutions:

1. [Quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667):

   ```
   $ printf "%s : %s : %s\n" "$TERM" "${TERM//[^[:alnum:]]/_}" "${TERM//[^[:alnum:]]/?}"
   xterm-256color : xterm_256color : xterm?256color
   ```
2. Turn off filename expansion

   ```
   $ (set -f; printf "%s : %s : %s\n" $TERM  ${TERM//[^[:alnum:]]/_} ${TERM//[^[:alnum:]]/?})
   xterm-256color : xterm_256color : xterm?256color
   ```
3. Turn off the `nullglob` shell option

   ```
   $ (shopt -u nullglob; printf "%s : %s : %s\n" $TERM  ${TERM//[^[:alnum:]]/_} ${TERM//[^[:alnum:]]/?})
   xterm-256color : xterm_256color : xterm?256color
   ```

Comment: That's it! and good link! Thanks. Although it doesn't seem to explain why the failure does NOT occur when within `tmux`.

Comment: Compare `echo "$-"` (`set` settings) and `shopt` between the 2 users/environments.

Comment: You're correct. option `nullglob` was set differently. Not sure why, as all are using the same `.bashrc`, but that's a separate thing.

Comment: Quoting the variable expansions is the correct solution. Setting `nullglob` and turning off filename expansions just to avoid quoting variables is a bit of a hack.

Comment: then there's also `shopt -s failglob` which would immediately complain instead of giving an odd result like in the question